# $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{3}\prod_{l=1}^k \frac{2+3l}{ 4\cdot 3(l+1)}\right)\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation

Limit of the series

$$\left(\frac{5}{3\cdot6}\right)\cdot\frac{1}{4} + \left(\frac{5\cdot8}{3\cdot6\cdot9}\right)\cdot\frac{1}{4^2} + \left(\frac{5\cdot8\cdot11}{3\cdot6\cdot9\cdot12}\right)\cdot\frac{1}{4^3} +.....$$

Try: Actually I was trying to do it by multiplying by $\frac{1}{4}$ and then substract by shifting one place but then I can't get any useful.....

A small hint is warmly appreciated .

Comment: An incomplete simplification of the general term is $$\frac{5(5+3)\cdots(5+3(n-1))}{4^n3^{n+1}(n+1)!}$$ but I can't do more.

Comment: For multiplication use `\cdot`, not `.`

Comment: It could perhaps be useful to note that the numerator in the form presented in the first comment can be put in the form
$$5^n[(1.6)(2.2)(2.8)(3.4)(4)]\cdot[(4.6)(5.2)(5.8)(6.4)(7)]\cdot[(7.6)(8.2)(8.8)(9.4)(10)]\cdots$$where every five factors are reproduced with the same decimal parts ($0.6, 0.2,0.8,0.4$) and the last of them is an integer $1$ till $4$;$4$ till $7$; $7$ till $10$ and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Hint

Note that after multiplying the series by $2\times 1/4$, you can reorganize each term into the form
$$
\frac{1}{n!} \left(\prod_{k=1}^n \frac{3k-1}{3}\right) \frac{1}{4^n}\ .
$$
This should indicate to you that this could be the power series of some function evaluated at $\frac{1}{4}$.

Now the product of the factors $(3k-1)/3 = k - 1/3$ should be the $n$-th derivative of some function. What kind of function has an $n$-th order derivative of this form? More specifically, we want a function whose $n$-th order derivative at $0$ can be obtained from multiplying its $(n-1)$-th order derivative by some factor, and this factor increase by $1$ each time you increase the order by $1$.

> Generically, $(1-x)^{k}$ for $k<0$ behaves like this. In this case, $k = - 2/3$. Of course you still need to subtract off the first few terms to get the exact form.

Comment: Small nitpick, the index in the product bracket should be k, not n.

Comment: @BenjaminWang Thank you for spotting that! Corrected now.